# Javascript exercise: Every possible option

Tags: javascript

I've found this [exercise](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-function-exercise-3.php)

But I didn't like it because it did not consider every possibility with the given input. So, I'm trying to extend the answer with more possibilities. So here's the challenge:

Given any string or number, return every possible combination.
Ex.: 123

Output would be:
1, 12, 13, 123, 132, 2, 21, 23, 213, 231, 3, 31, 32, 312, 321.

No repeated items such as 11, 111, 112, etc.

My code so far ( be gentle. ;p )

```
let n = 123 + '';
let x = n.split('');
let answer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    answer.push( x[i] );
    if ( i === 0) {
        for (let a = 0; a < x.length - 1; a++){
            answer.push( x[i] + '' + x[i + (a + 1)]);   
        }
    }
    else if ( i > 0 && i !== (x.length - 1) ){
        for (let a = 0; a < i; a++){
            answer.push( x[i] + '' + x[a]);
        }
        for (let a = i + 1; a < x.length; a++){
            answer.push( x[i] + '' + x[a]);
        }
    }
    else if (i === (x.length - 1)) {

        for (let a = x.length; a > 1; a--){
            answer.push( x[i] + '' + x[i - (a - 1)]);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is that our challenge or yours?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code challenge / code golf site....

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz I wanna know how would people solve it. I'm trying it myself.

Comment: @TheCog, I'll update the question with my code so far.

Comment: Now, what's the problem with the code?

Comment: @Teemu My code? I'm stuck in getting every item together, like 123. Trying to figure out. But for now I'll go ahead and get things done from 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dynamic approach for any size of  items, by taking one element out of the array, get the rest combinations and later put that element to the former position into the array.

Then take the actual element and add it to the result set. Then try to get the combinations of the rest array and map it to the result set as well.

```js
function x(array) {
    var i, l, element, temp, result = [];
    for (i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        element = array.splice(i, 1);
        result.push(element)
        temp = x(array);
        if (temp.length) {
            result = result.concat(temp.map(a => element.concat(a)));
        }
        array.splice(i, 0, element[0]);
    }
return result;
}

console.log(x([...'123']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Geez, that was fast. That's an awesome approach. I'm still trying my pitiful way to do it, but yours is amazing.